Change font size in "flashcards" document class from Overleaf
I'm using the flashcards document class in an Overleaf document. I want to change the font size, but I can't find a way to do it. I've tried \documentclass[10pt,avery5371,grid]{flashcards} (the other two arguments are for formatting the output) but it doesn't work.
I am using this example to make my own flashcards, the following would be a MWE:
\documentclass[avery5371,grid]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}
\cardfrontfoot{Calculus I}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{datetime}

\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}[Formula]{quadratic formula}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
The solutions or roots of the quadratic equation \\
$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ are given by
\begin{equation*}
x = \dfrac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation*}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

please provide a complete minimal example. what is the default font size? which font are you using? is it available in 10pt?

Because of the missing MWE just some notes: flashcards loads article but does not pass options to it. It also does not provide font size options like 10pt on its own. So 10pt is unknown. You could indeed use \PassOptionsToClass to pass a font size option to article. Or you can use a package like scrextend. If you want to change the size of only some elements see the flashcards documentation for commands \cardfrontstyle etc. They all have an optional argument to change the font.

@cfr I've just added a MWE. Could you please have a look at it?

note that 10pt is the default for article anyway. so you wouldn't expect using that to change anything. try what @cabohah suggested with 11pt or 12pt and you should see a difference.

“The following would be a MWE.” No, it isn't. A MWE has to show the problem, but your example doesn't even show an attempt to change any font size — neither the font size bases of the document nor any other font size. And even using 10pt as additional option would a warning message, but as cfr already told 10pt is the default of article and therefore of flashcards. So if the warning message is the problem, the current example would already be the solution.

BTW: If you want vertically centered backsides you should not use \vspace*, but remove \cardbackstyle{empty}.

The flashcards package does not offer any options for changing the font size that I am aware of, but you can wrap each card with a fontsize option to change the font size. It's a bit of a kludge and not very elegant, but it works:
\documentclass[avery5371,grid]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}
\cardfrontfoot{Calculus I}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{datetime}

\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}[Formula]{quadratic formula}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
{\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont
The (10pt) solutions or roots of the quadratic equation \\
$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ are given by
\begin{equation*}
x = \dfrac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation*}
}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}


\begin{flashcard}[Formula]{quadratic formula}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
The solutions or roots of the quadratic equation \\
$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ are given by
\begin{equation*}
x = \dfrac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation*}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}


\end{document}


